# Average for all values within a range

Tags: excel, vba, statistics, range, average

I would like to store the average value for all (numerical, constant) data stored in a range in a variable.

```
k = average(Range(cells(15, 27)Cells(i-1, 27))
```

It appears to me that I define the range wrong, where is my syntax error? Thank you very much for your help.

Second iteration:

```
 k = Average(Range(Cells(15, 27))(Cells(i - 1, 27))
```

It seems that VBA does not understand "Average" as function although I found it online. https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/average-a-range-of-cells-in-vba.292819/

Comment: This link you refer to clearly does not mention Average as being a valid VBA function/method. It's either used in reference to a formula as a string, or through a reference to the worksheet function. That being said, your referenced range also does not seem to follow valid syntax.

Comment: okay thank you, that is at least a good pointer.

Comment: For the `ActiveSheet`, you could use e.g. `k = Application.Average(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5)))`.

Comment: thank you very much helping me find my syntax error!

Answer (score 0):

These seem to work, you can use the worksheet functions.

```
Range("H3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("H15:H999")) 
  
Range("H4") = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Range("H15:H999"))
```

I wish I could insert a check for the last filled cell, so that I avoid including any values by chance that are much below the range I want to analyse. Would be great if you had any ideas.